# Help! 508 compliant CAPTCHA

Tags: recaptcha

We are looking for  a CAPTCHA framework that is section 508 compliant.  That means it must have the audio read out feature for visually disabled people.

Do you know of a CAPTCHA framework other than reCaptcha that is 508 Compliant, apart from reCaptcha ( Google owned)?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use reCaptcha?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://www.captcha.net/?

Answer (score 0):

I think this page can be very useful:
http://www.evengrounds.com/developers/is-captcha-section-508-compliant